# Force Aspect Ratio when user Resizing AVPlayerView - Swift OS X Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I would like to be able to force an AVPlayerView to have a 16:9 aspect ratio, even if the user decides to resize the window.

Right now I have it so that my view opens automatically with a 16:9 ratio (800x450)

Screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKg1.jpg

the problem is, if the user decides to resize the window, the aspect ratio can get skewed and would result in large black rectangles around the video.

Screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Iqt.jpg

Any possible ways of effectively keeping/forcing the aspect ratio in swift?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard for the constraints?

Comment: no, basically just a viewcontroller, with a AVKit Player View as its root.  I just figured it out though.  Just needed to add .  self.view.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(width: 16, height: 9)     into viewDidAppear

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out basically just need to set .aspectRatio of the window view in viewDidAppear():

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(width: 16, height: 9)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SwiftUI, Xcode 11, Swift 5, macOS Catalina, single window app**

For a single-window, SwiftUI macOS app, you can set a fixed aspect ratio to allow proportional resizing for the parent window of your SwiftUI stack by modifying the applicationDidFinishLaunching() in the **AppDelegate.swift**

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // …
        // set a fixed aspect ratio of the main window in a macOS app for SwiftUI
        window.contentView?.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(width: 9, height: 16)
        // continue with your regularly scheduled program…  
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```